# Problem on Cauchy Problem solutions homeomorphic to a disc

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $\mathscr{U}=\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the continuous function  $f:\mathscr{U}\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose there are two solutions $\varphi_1,\varphi_2:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ of $\dot{x}=f(t,x)$ such that $\varphi_1(0)=\varphi_2(0)$ and the graphics of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ draw a region on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is homeomorphic to the disc $B$. Show that for all $(t,x)\in B$ there is a solution $\varphi$ of the diferential equation that passes through the points $(0,\varphi_1(0))$,$(t,x)$ and $(1,\varphi_1(1))$

I know that a non-injective solution of the problem is homeomorphic to a circumference $S_1$. However I have no idea on how to tackle this problem. I am still getting the hang on problems of this kind.

**Question**:

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $f$ just any continuous function or do we have a further hypothesis? Does your hypothesis mean that $\varphi_1(1)=\varphi_2(1)$?

Comment: @Mindlack           $f$ is just a continuous function. Since it is not          Lipschitz continuous I cannot apply the Picard theorem, but Peano theorem assures at least a solution since $dim(R^2)=2$.  The hypothesis is only on $\varphi_1(0)=\varphi_2(0)$

Comment: But the graphics of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ won’t define any region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ unless the functions are the same at $1$, will they?

Comment: @Mindlack Sorry, I am not following. Why 1? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: How exactly do you define the region drawn by the graphics of the $\varphi_k$?

Comment: @Mindlack             Sincerely, I do not know. I understand it must close so that we have a limited region. Why at t=1?

Comment: Also, assume that we allow $\varphi_1(1) \neq \varphi_2(1)$. Choose $f$ such that $f$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$ on $\{t > 1/2\}$, and consider a point $P=(2/3,u)$ where $u \neq \varphi_1(2/3)$. Then there is no integral curve going through $(1,\varphi_1(1))$ and $P$, essentially by the uniqueness in Picard-Lindelof.

Comment: @ Pedro Gomes: If it doesn’t close at $t=1$, it leaves something completely open there...

Comment: @Mindlack How did you apply Picard's Theorem? We do not have the information that $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: I wrote : “ choose $f$ so that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\{t > 1/2\}$.” So in this situation we can apply Picard to get a uniqueness around $t=1$.

Comment: Can you assume that $f$ is smooth on $\mathscr{C}^1$ for this problem? I am not understanding that step.

Comment: The statement is supposed to hold for every $f$, in particular for $f$ that are smooth on some parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming $\varphi_1(1)=\varphi_2(1)$, and I am denoting $D=\{(t,x),\, 0 \leq t \leq 1,\, \min(\varphi_1(t),\varphi_2(t)) \leq x \leq \max(\varphi_1(t),\varphi_2(t))\}$ the region between $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$.

If for some $0 < t < 1$, $\varphi_1(t) = \varphi_2(t)$, then there are two disjoint non-empty open subsets of $D$ such that their reunion is $D$ minus a singleton; this is impossible in $B$. So we may assume $\varphi_1 < \varphi_2$ on $(0,1)$.

Our goal is to show the following: if $y: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an integral curve the graph of which is contained in $D$, where $(s,t) \subset I \subset [s,t] \subset [0,1]$ then there is an interval $J \supset [s,t]$ such that $J$ is open in $[0,1]$, and $y$ extends to an integral curve with graphics contained in $D$ and defined on $J$.

Assume first $I=[s,t]$. We can find small integral curves starting left of $s$ from $(s,y(s))$, such that they remain in $D$ (if $(s,y(s))$ is not on the border, we can restrict the existence interval, else we take the corresponding $\varphi_k$). We do the same on the right for $t$.

Then, we need to show that if $I=(s,t)$, $y$ extends uniquely as an integral curve to $[s,t]$. It is enough (because $f$ is continuous) to show that $y$ has a unique continuous extension to $[s,t]$. This holds provided $y$ is uniformly continuous. Now, since $y$ is in the compact $D$, $|y’| \leq \sup\,|f|(D)$ so $y$ is Lipschitz continuous so uniformly continuous and then we are done.

Now consider a point $(t,x) \in D$. Define $V$ to be the set of $(I,u)$ such that $I$ is a nontrivial interval containing $t$, and $u : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an integral curve the graphics of which is contained in $D$, such that $u(t)=x$.

Endow $V$ with the following order: $(I,u) \leq (J,v)$ iff $V \supset u$ and $v_{|I}=u$.

By Peano, $V$ is nonempty. By what we wrote earlier, the maximal elements of $V$ are integral curves $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that their graphics go through $(0,\varphi_1(0))$, $(t,x)$, $(1,\varphi_1(1))$. It is obvious that any totally ordered subset of $V$ is bounded above. Then we conclude using Zorn’s lemma.

Edit: I found a way to bypass the need for Zorn lemma. The important part is the following argument.

Given an increasing sequence of open intervals $(a_n,b_n)$, the “limit” of which is $(\alpha,\beta)$, and integral curves $u_n$ on $(a_n,b_n)$ mapping $t$ to $x$ with a graph contained in $D$, there is a subsequence $u_{i_n}$ that converges uniformly on every compact subset of $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Then the limit $v$ of the $u_{i_n}$ is defined on $(\alpha,\beta)$ and is an integral curve the graph of which is contained in $D$, because the ODE can be represented as an integral form.

The end runs as follows: let $S_1$ be the set of real numbers $0 \leq r < t$ such that there exists  an integral curve $u$ defined on $(r,t]$, with graph in $D$, and $S_2$ be the same (but right of $t$).

Then both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are nonempty (Peano), closed (by what is just above), and open (by what was before the “edit” part), so they contain $0$ and $1$, which is what we wanted to prove.